# Proof: $ker(g) \subset ker(f)$ ..

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Let $V = \mathbb{R}_{\le 3} [x]$ with basis $ B = (1, x, x^2, x^3)$.

And $f: V \to \mathbb{R}, p \to \int_{-1}^1 p(x) dx$ and

$g: V \to \mathbb{R}^3, p \to ^t( p(-1), p(0), p(1) )$.

(1) I had to determine $M_{B \eta} (f)$ and $M_{B \eta (g)}$. [I suppose that $\eta$ means standardbasis of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the other case! Correct me, if I am wrong. The exercise doesn't say any more]

I determined

$M_{B \eta} (f) = (2, 0, \frac{2}{3}, 0)$

$M_{B \eta} (g) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

In order to do so, I took a look at $f(1) = ... = 2, f(x) = 0, f(x^2)= 2/3, f(x^3)=0$ and $g(1) = (1,1,1), g(x) = (-1, 0, 1), g(x^2) = (1, 0, 1), g(x^3) = (-1, 0, 1)$.

---

Now by taking a look at those two matrices:

$M_{B \eta} (g) = ... = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow ker(g) = span\{x - x^3\}$.

Since $f(x-x^3) = f(x) - f(x^3) = 0 - 0$ (as I computed above) it is $ker(g) \subseteq ker(f)$.

But why is $ker(g) \subset ker(f)$ ?

$ker(g)$ has dimension 2, right?

What's the span of $ker(f)$? Since $M_{B \eta} (f) = (2,0, \frac{2}{3}, 0)$ it has dimension 2, right?

Comment: $\mathrm{ker}(g)$ has dimension one, you wrote yourself it was spanned by only one element.

Answer (score 1):

We have: $p\in\ker(g)\iff p(-1)=p(0)=p(1)=0\iff p(x)=\lambda x(x+1)(x-1)=\lambda x(x^2-1)$
and we have $f(p)=0$ since $p$ is odd hence $p\in \ker (f)$. Conclude.

**Remark:** Notice that $f$ is a linear form so $\ker(f)$ is an hyperplan of $V$ so
$$\dim\ker(f)=\dim V-1=3$$

Comment: Wel $\lambda x(x^2-1) \in ker(g)$ and $\lambda x(x^2-1) \in ker(f)$. However, $ µ(1 - 3x^2) \in ker(f)$ but $µ (1-3x^2) \not \in ker(g)$. I see this since f(1) = 2, f(x^2) = 2/3. Can't I compute this by using $M_{B \eta} (f) = (2,0, \frac{2}{3}, 0$ ? I want to get a result so that $ker(f) = span\{x, x^3, 1-3x^2\}$

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can I calculate $ker(f) = span\{x, x^3, 1-3x^2\}$ directly?

Comment: Let $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and calculate $f(p)=0$ and find the possible values of $a,b,c$ and $d$.